# Check if scrollbar could be focused/scrolled in WebBrowser

Tags: .net, vb.net, browser, scrollbar

Is it possible to check if the scrollbar of a webbrowser can be scrolled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try doing a request for the height of the screen and cross-checking it with the height of the document. As the scroller is only enabled when the document's height/width is bigger than the screen's width you can use this to check can it be scrolled.

You can use this for your screen height:

`My.Computer.Screen.Bounds`

And this for your browsers open webpage height:

```
Dim docWidth as Integer 
Dim docHeight as Integer

docHeight = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height
docWidth = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width
```